# WP_cron keeps going back to the past

Tags: wp-cron

When I execute this command `wp cron event list`, this is the output:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------+
| hook                                                              | next_run_gmt        | next_run_relative    | recurrence    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------+
| action_scheduler_run_queue                                        | 2021-04-28 08:11:04 | now                  | 1 minute      |
| jetpack_sync_cron                                                 | 2021-04-28 08:11:13 | now                  | 5 minutes     |
| jetpack_sync_full_cron                                            | 2021-04-28 08:13:19 | now                  | 5 minutes     |
| woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders                                  | 2021-04-28 08:14:53 | now                  | Non-repeating |
...
```

I can execute the cron manually, the list gets more empty, the next run date will update correctly.
But... after +- 5 minutes this list is there again, with the same date/time as in the past.
The cron itself is working, so no problem with that.

I've been searching for this problem for hours, but cannot find the cause of this.

Disabled almost all the plugins I've got, no difference.

Tried to manually delete the `cron` entry from `wp_options` => it's working again, but after a few minutes, the list with old entries is here again.

Maybe someone over here knows the magic? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference if someone else has the same problem.

Found out that the high availability of the database cluster was causing this. For some weird reason another server was sending old data back to the mysql server on which this wordpress site is connected at the moment.

The strange thing is that it was only the cron row in wp_options that was affected with this, but the important part is that the cause has been found.

The cause was not wordpress related itself, but still only affecting wordpress for some reason...